# Как сделать блок прозрачным для ссылок?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок-ссылка, поверх него другой блок. Как сделать чтобы при клике по верхнему срабатывала нижняя ссылка?

Вроде какое-то CSS свойство есть... Прошу НЕ ПИШИТЕ про opacity и z-index! Мне нужно чтобы внешне ничего не изменилось, а верхний блок сделался как-бы прозрачным для ссылки снизу.

Comment: Пример дайте, прозрачность можно через `background` сделать, другой вопрос если прозрачность нужна для JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В современных браузерах есть свойство CSS `pointer-events`. Если задать ему значение `none`, то элемент становистя "прозрачным" для событий мыши. IE на данный момент это свойство не поддерживает, но вы можете воспользоваться хаком с `filter`.

Для современных браузеров:

```
pointer-events: none;
background: url('your_transparent.png');
```

Для IE11:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_transparent.png', sizingMethod='scale');
background: none !important;
```

В старых браузерах, в том числе в IE10- это не работает. Если эта функциональность критична для использования сайта, то пока лучше её избегать.

См. [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/293099).

Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то вам придётся вручную форвардить сообщения. Решения можно найти по ссылке выше.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я два часа в гугле убил... opacity всякие вылазят :)